# How to execute shell command

Tags: bash, go, exec

I have some trouble with execute shell commands from a Go program:

```
  var command = pwd + "/build " + file_name

  dateCmd := exec.Command(string(command))
  dateOut, err := dateCmd.Output()
  check(err)
```

If `command` variable equals a single word like `/home/slavik/project/build` (build is shell script) it works, but if I try to pass some arg i.e. `/home/slavik/project/build xxx` or `/home/slavik/project/build -v=1` the Go program raises an exception like `file /home/slavik/project/build not found`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Take a look here, too: https://gobyexample.com/execing-processes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass the program and the arguments separately. See the signature of [exec.Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command):

```
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
```

So if you want to pass e.g. `-v=1`, your call probably should look something like:

```
dateCmd := exec.Command(pwd + "/build", "-v=1")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
exec.Command(pwd + "/build", fileName)
```